# How to get objects from inside a block and use it in another class or method?

Tags: ios, afnetworking, objective-c-blocks

I'm beginner in ios. This is a simple code example with AFNetworking.

```
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourServerAddress.com/"]];
[httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFFormURLParameterEncoding];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET"
                                                        path:@"http://yourServerAddress.com/example?name=foo"
                                                  parameters:nil];
[httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [httpClient HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


                                            NSLog(@"Response: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
                                        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                            //-- This block gets invoked when the operation fails
                                            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                                        }];
```

The responseObject would be printed to the console, but my question is : How to get responseObject and use it in an another class or methods?

EDIT 1:

I'm tried to use a method :

```
- (void)responseFromBlock:(id)response {

NSLog(@"responseObject from the block : %@",response);
```

}

And i'm use it inside the block :

```
 [self responseFromBlock:responseObject];
```

But the answer is:

```
response object from the block : <7b226572 726f7222 3a7b2263 6f646522 3a313230 307d2c22 72657375 6c74223a 5b7b2263 6964223a 22313234 222c2263 6e616d65 223a2244 69766174 227d2c7b 22636964...
```

Comment: You should learn Object-oriented Programming before starting programming iOS application. "Programming in Objective C 2.0" is a good book for starter. This problem is easy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might look like this:

```
@interface YourClassDealingWithAFNetworking

@property (nonatomic, retain) id object;

@end
```

And then inside the block:

```
self.object = responseObject;
```

Now you've got it and can use it wherever you need

just don't forget to release it in dealloc:

```
self.object = nil;
```